# How do you convert a String to a float or int?

Tags: arduino

In an Arduino program I'm working on the GPS sends the coordinates to the arduino through USB. Because of this, the incoming coordinates are stored as Strings. Is there any way to convert the GPS coordinates to a float or int?

I've tried     `int gpslong = atoi(curLongitude)` and     `float gpslong = atof(curLongitude)`, but they both cause Arduino to give an error:

```
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get an `int` from a `String` by just calling [`toInt`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt) on the `String` object (e.g. `curLongitude.toInt()`).

If you want a `float`, you can use `atof` in conjunction with the [`toCharArray`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) method:

```
char floatbuf[32]; // make this at least big enough for the whole string
curLongitude.toCharArray(floatbuf, sizeof(floatbuf));
float f = atof(floatbuf);
```

Comment: The toInt works properly thanks. How exactly do I use the toCharArray in this case? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Xjkh3vk: added an example.

Answer (score 4):

**`c_str()`** will give you the string buffer const char* pointer.
.
So you can use your convertion functions:. 
`int gpslong = atoi(curLongitude.c_str())`
`float gpslong = atof(curLongitude.c_str())`

Comment: Note that these are Arduino `String`s, not C++ `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

How about `sscanf(curLongitude, "%i", &gpslong)` or `sscanf(curLongitude, "%f", &gpslong)`? Depending on how the strings look, you might have to modify the format string, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to Long in Arduino IDE:

```
    //stringToLong.h

    long stringToLong(String value) {
        long outLong=0;
        long inLong=1;
        int c = 0;
        int idx=value.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<=idx;i++){

            c=(int)value[idx-i];
            outLong+=inLong*(c-48);
            inLong*=10;
        }

        return outLong;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
String stringOne, stringTwo, stringThree;
int a;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  stringOne = 12; //String("You added ");
  stringTwo = String("this string");
  stringThree = String();
  // send an intro:
  Serial.println("\n\nAdding Strings together (concatenation):");
  Serial.println();enter code here
}

void loop() {
  // adding a constant integer to a String:
  stringThree =  stringOne + 123;
  int gpslong =(stringThree.toInt());
  a=gpslong+8;
  //Serial.println(stringThree);    // prints "You added 123"
  Serial.println(a);    // prints "You added 123"
}
```

Comment: This is an English-only site. Also, this answer doesn't add anything useful and doesn't explain what it's doing (and is very over-complicated).

Comment: *'prints "You added 123"'* None of those lines print that.