# Converting a substring to integer with toInt

Tags: c++, ajax, string, arduino

For an arduino project, I want to convert an Ajax request which looks like this:

> String request = "GET /setAlarm&h=21&m=34&end"

I am trying to exctract the "21" and "34" as integers and to save them in two variables.

The substring method is working, since I can output the right info with

```
Serial.println(request.substring(request.indexOf("&h=") + 3, request.indexOf("&m=")))
```

So far I tried using `.toInt`, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200065/12288557. My code for the hour looks like this:

```
int hour = request.substring(request.indexOf("&h=") + 3, request.indexOf("&m=")).toInt;
```

Using `.toInt` Visual Studio gives me the following error message:

> error: cannot convert 'String::toInt' from type 'long int (String::)()const' to type 'int
>      int hour = request.substring(request.indexOf("&h=") + 3, request.indexOf("&m=")).toInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toInt()` is a function, so you need to put parenthesis after it, since C++ requires this for all functions:

```
request.substring(request.indexOf("&h=") + 3, request.indexOf("&m=")).toInt();
```